# How to send text to input field with dynamic @id

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have tried looking for solutions all around SO and integrated answers to no avail. I am trying to fill up dynamic `@id` forms and applying my code logic to both my test site and udemy does not seem to work.

```
driver.get('https://www.udemy.com/')
#search= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"-search-form-autocomplete--3")')
s = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"-search-form-autocomplete--3")')))
s.send_keys("robotics")
```

Comment: What error it is throwing

Comment: Can you explain the error, you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpath is not closed properly the closing `]` is missing hence may be the exception. Another thing is please add the necessary imports

when I fixed the xpath your code did worked for me -

Code after fix-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.udemy.com/')
#search= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"-search-form-autocomplete--3")')
s = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"-search-form-autocomplete--3")]')))
s.send_keys("robotics")
```

Imports needed -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output -**

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh, the cursed syntax error.. -.- Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` in your code?